# Debian Nginx PHP-FPM session_start()

Tags: web, nginx, debian, php

Today I installed Nginx (last version), mysql 5.5 and PHP-FPM on my little debian
Everything works fine except....

When I tried to use: `session_start()` I got:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function start_session()".

I guess I need to install SESSION support for PHP-FPM? What is the option to install it?

**Note:** Everything was installed with source (and I don't want to use apt-get for nginx, mysql or php-fpm)

**Note2:** already searched on SO or Google but I couldn't find the option/flag or lib to install for the sessions on PHP-FPM.

Any ideas?

ty

EDIT: mybad the function was session_start() and not start_session() :D

Comment: Is it `session_start` or `start_session` ?

Comment: The error is still saying that start_session() doesn't exist. Even in php fpm and nginx the session support is enabled by default and works out of the box. Maybe you should try to post the relevant part of your code.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @air4x in comment. The right function to use is [session_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

The [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/session.installation.php) support is enabled in PHP by default, so unless you compiled your php with the `--disable-session` directive you have it installed.

Answer (score 1):

The correct function to use is:

```
session_start();
```

More on sessions here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php